# register_theme_directory in plugin not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to register a theme folder within my plugin directory so that I can have "standard" themes for pages and stuff. Users can overwrite these in their own theme folder if they wish, but at least there is a "skeleton" for users.

I have found out about the function `register_theme_directory()` but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('init', 'test_templates_dir');
function test_templates_dir(){
    $plugindir = dirname( __FILE__ );
    register_theme_directory($plugindir."/themefiles");
}
```

Inside my `$plugindir."/themefiles"` directory I have a file called `tpl-directory.php` and inside that template file I have this:

```
<?php
/*
 *Template name: Directory template
 */
?>
```

This isn't coming up in the list of available templates when I'm "adding new" pages however.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone know? Or does anyone know a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve? I have read that there are no filters or hooks in order to "add template files manually" (although I would be pretty happy with that if I can do it that way!).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but that function only works to make wp look on that folder for more themes, not page templates.

Apparently there's no way to add a page template to the current active theme, but you can either catch the current type of content to load a specific template from inside the plugin, or add a new template file inside the current theme on activation.

See this thread for more details:
[WP - Use file in plugin directory as custom Page Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template)

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Silly me, thanks for this! :) And thanks for the link.