# Need to include a custom template page through a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

is there any way to include a custom template from a folder inside my plugin page into the Wordpress system so that when I, for example create a new page/post, it can show as one of the template choices other than default of course.
I have seen this link here [WP - Use file in plugin directory as custom Page Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template) but does not seem to talk about the stage were Wordpress checks for custom templates in the themes directory and how to make it look else where.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the documentation because WordPress doesn't look elsewhere.  Your best bet would be to [create a template page](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/13/page-templates-the-untapped-potential-of-wordpress) in your theme folder, call it what you want, and then use `include()` to pull the contents of your template file in the plugins directory into the file in your theme directory, which would allow WordPress to see it.

I think the only other way to accomplish this would be to mess with Core, which is very bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it not documented so i was hoping someone had found a work around to solve the problem. Since its a plugin, by its very nature it means i can't have the custom template  in the theme directory and would have to manually put it there for every theme that wants to use the plugin,kinda like woo-commerce plugins, and i do not want to hack the core for obvious reasons, guess i'm stuck.