# Open a page with unique url for each subscriber in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm relatively new in WP plugins and this is kind a blocker for me, sorry if it's too simple.

I have a plugin with admin panel for control of some values in a form.
I would like to show the form hosted on a page with a unique url (hashed) for each subscriber, so: domainname/REFER_SLUG?uniquekey

For example when user click on some link on the site.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Create a custom post type and assign a taxonomy to it. [Read more here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/when-do-you-need-a-custom-post-type-or-taxonomy-in-wordpress/).

Comment: @dingo_d This placed me even deeper in a whole. What exactly that taxonomy will to for me?
I was thinking, if I create a page inside of my plugin directory and a link which has REFER_SLUG value (defined in admin panel) and some unique key, how can I make sure that that link will point to the page I create inside of the plugin directory?

Comment: Creating a custom post type and taxonomy is super simple, and will create all you need and more. You can have archive page for all your taxonomies (post category is a taxonomy for post type), single page, etc. You'll have the ability to create slugs (via taxonomy). It's worth a bit of exploring, rather than just hacking something fast. Anyways, if you have a plugin, maybe that plugin already has a defined custom post type and taxonomy. In that case you don't need to do anything, just some simple querying...

Comment: So, let's say I want to use taxonomy. Will that mean that the admin will need to do some adjustments after my plugin is activated in order to make everything working?

This is what I found which sounds close to what I need:
[custom page template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328475/adding-custom-page-template-from-plugin)

Do you think that this is doable?

Comment: Well if you are making a plugin, then the custom post type, and taxonomy are a must, and admin needs only to add categories to your taxonomy (or whatever you label your taxonomy for that custom post). I mean, I don't understand, what do you expect your plugin to do? Automatically grab values or do you want the user to input them?

Comment: So, I'm creating a referral plugin. After activation the admin is able to access the settings of the plugin and change them (referral msg, thank you msg, etc.). The referral takes place using a form hosted on a page with a unique url (hashed) for each subscriber, so: domain/REFER_SLUG?uniquekey.
After submitting that form the referrer gets some reward and the referred person gets some discount reward.

Comment: Then custom post type won't help. It's a more complicated then what I thought. You need to asign a uniqueid to a subscriber, store this along with the e-mail and key, that you can use later on. Not a simple thing to do...