# how can create a WordPress page in plugin folder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to create a php page in plugin's folder of as plugin that i download. I create a page in hello plugin(hello is my downloaded plugin name) manually using dream viewer.Now how can i assign all WordPress property,plugin property to that page. i write

```
require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php")
```

But that page didn't get the properties of a page ,that we normally created by  add new page in WordPress dashboard..It's not about get_header,get_footer.get_footer functions.
I want to create the new page for execute do_short code function ,so i can execute the plugin part in my created new page.Normally we execute the plugin short code in word press pages by copying that short code to text editor of edit pages and update it. .So I  looking for a solution.Please help if you know the answer.

Comment: I might be wrong, and I might not understand the question - but it seems that you are absolutely clueless about plugins , and I suspect that answering your question involves more than a one - liner ( like a full wp - programming course ..). Please read here as a start .. http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: normally we execute plugin short code by pasting it in text editor under Edit Page and update that page.If my post name is portfolio then clicking the portfolio link in front end or client side we can see the portfolio section .Here my problem is that i must need to create a new page in plugins folder ,and there were do_shortcode function so that i can run that page and get output ,by directly giving url on my browser.. do you under stand the question?

Comment: Yes, I do understand the question, but you can might as well go ahead and rename your question to " how to write a wp plugin " . So I had a link in the previous comment to help you with that .

Comment: can you please look this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520284/how-do-i-create-a-new-page-with-the-plugin-im-building .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you shouldn't be doing this at all and that there is a better solution.

If you need a page template I don't know why you wouldn't just create a new page template file in your theme root folder. That way you can just create a new page in the WP admin and assign it to that page template. Then you can execute whatever code you want in the page template.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

If you really need to create a new page on plugin activation you can do that.

```
$my_page = array(
    'post_title' => 'Our New Auto-Created Page',
    'post_content' => 'This is a new page. You can add any content you want here, including shortcodes.',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_page);
```

You should probably check if a page with that title exists first though. That way you don't create a new page everytime the plugin has been activated.

Now if you want to use a page template for your auto created page and store that template in your plugin folder, then you'll have to create a page template within your plugin and use a template redirect. A template redirect will let WordPress know what template to use for your page and where it is located.

[WP - Use file in plugin directory as custom Page Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

An alternative to a template redirect would be creating a page template file in the theme root programmatically on plugin activation. It would be easiest to have the template already created in your plugin, then copy it to the theme root. Then you can programmatically assign the page you created to the template you just copied to the theme root and it will just work without any template redirect.

Pseudocode:

```
if (false === file_exists($path_to_file_in_theme_root) {
    copy($page_template_in_plugin_foler, $path_to_file_in_theme_root);
}
```

Comment: I have a plugin.And it has a short code for execution.So after doing the needed setup and changes in the plugin from wordpress dashbaord i get the short code.                                                                                         reqirement is that i have to execute the plugin independently in a page ,for this i use do_shortcode['shortcode'].when i call the page from browser (eg:http://localhost/gift/wp-content/plugins/hello /camwqpaigns.php?id=4) ,need to get the result. so i write require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php"); .,get the result,but it is not working properly,

Comment: @Justin - Please read my comment to the original Question. It is not about "pages" as intended by a regular wp lingo. The op is talking about admin pages inside a plugin hook... The question can basically be titled `"how to write a wp plugin" `

Comment: @Justin your answer is really helpful for me.even now i didn't know how to create a new page when the activation of plugin.Really great.

Comment: can you please look this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520284/how-do-i-create-a-new-page-with-the-plugin-im-building